# How would i rename images sequentially that are within a directory structure using automator

Tags: image, directory-structure, automator, renaming, sequencing

(I have a Music Library folder - within that there are folders and subfolders - in the subfolders there are images - I need to rename these images cover.xxx cover1.xxx cover2.xxx etc and repeat for each directory. it's important to not change the suffix as they may be different formats. Many Thanks for you help - Merry Christmas

Answer (score 0):

@Adam Theuma, this question can be classified in to two ways,
1. are you a programmer? (if yes) then you can write a console application that imports files and dose the magic for you. 
2. If not a programmer then check out this link, make sure to do a thrill comparison of the various tools available here:
https://www.slant.co/topics/6970/~windows-tools-for-renaming-files#3

Hopefully this helps. I am just trying to see if this could benefit you in any way.
Good luck!!

Comment: OP is using a Mac so Windows tools won't be any use.

Comment: @MarkSetchell my bad, I didn't see any indication of the operating system/mac. I am a windows user, and I do use the same terminologies. If Mac is the case then I will come up with alternative suggestions. Thanks tho :-)

Comment: https://www.imore.com/how-rename-multiple-files-once-mac maybe this could do the trick